# Spring boot pageable is not working with where clause

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I tried to use spring pageable with `Where` clause and containing but it returns nothing.

My Spring version : 2.1.4.RELEASE

Database : MySql

```
public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<ItemEntity, String> {

    List<ItemEntity> findByCodeIgnoreCaseContainingAndNameIgnoreCaseContaining(String code, String name);

}
```

Comment: Can you show your JPA or MySQL query?

Answer (score 0):

Either Change the JPA Query as below :

```
Page<User> findByCodeIgnoreCaseContainingAndNameIgnoreCaseContaining(String code, String name,Pageable pageable);
```

Or use PagingAndSortingRepository instead of JpaRepository.

Please refer https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-pagination-sorting

Comment: JpaRepository extends the PagingAndSortingRepository, so it's not an issue with JpaRepository.